# the values are not reflected in the database after insertion azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I try to copy data from file in blob storage into sql server,i used azure logic app,all strep work fine but the value never insert into the table,how can i resole this issue
Here is my workflow and the stored procedure

[image]

[image]

Queries that i used:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL BlobCredential
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=SAS_TOKEN_HERE'; i used the sas token without ?


CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureBlob
WITH ( 
    TYPE       = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION   = 'link of my containers',
    CREDENTIAL = BlobCredential
);

CREATE TABLE Test (
    ID int,
    VALUE nvarchar(400)
)

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE LoadDataintoAzureSQL2
AS
BEGIN
TRUNCATE table [dbo].[Test];
BULK INSERT [dbo].[Test]
FROM 'input.csv'
WITH ( 
    DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureBlob',
    FORMAT      = 'CSV',
    FIRSTROW    = 2
);
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is might be due to the Location that you have mentioned while the `DATA SOURCE`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE dataset
WITH ( 
    TYPE       = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION   = 'https://<STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<YOUR CONTAINER NAME>',
    CREDENTIAL = Credentials
);
```

Inorder to get your credentials try giving your `SAS SIGNATURE` without '?' in the beginning.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL Credentials
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = '<YOUR SAS without '?'>'
```

Here is the Stored Procedure that I used

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE LoadDataintoAzureSQL2
AS
BEGIN
TRUNCATE table [dbo].[Products];
BULK INSERT [dbo].[Products]
FROM 'Products.csv'
WITH ( 
    DATA_SOURCE = 'dataset',
    FORMAT      = 'CSV',
    FIRSTROW    = 2
);
END
```

**REFERENCES:**
[Quick, easy and cheap way to automate data loading from CSV file into Azure SQL](https://marczak.io/posts/azure-loading-csv-to-sql/)

Comment: i used the same step but always the same problem,the location that i used is correct and used sasa signature with "?" and i sued the same procedure

Comment: you should not use "?" try removing it while giving SAS

Comment: I mean without "?",i didn't used it

Comment: What was the error that you are receiving?

Comment: I didn't receive a error,i checked my table ,the values never inserted,the table is empty

Comment: can you please try with the above suggested stored procedure

Comment: yes i already try it,but i got the same problem the table is always empty

Comment: Can you please try rechecking into which table you are inserting the values

Comment: I checked it,it's correct,i don't know why the values never inserted

Comment: I used sql server authentication for the database,is that the reason ?

Comment: If you weren't getting any 503 errors then I guess there is no issue with SQL Server Connection too

Comment: No i ddin't getting error,alson the file in output is created and the work flow executed successfully,but the table is still empty

Comment: Can you please try adding the csv file once again to the container instead of modifying it

Comment: I try to add a new line, i got error 502,bulk load failed due to invalid column value in csv data file

Comment: Even I received the same when tried to using wrong location of our storage account after changing the location to right url I could able to insert the values also Can you please add the queries you are trying now

Comment: i used the right url,i copied it into properties,which queries?

Comment: the SQL queries and the stored procedure

Comment: I added the procedure and queries in my post,thank you

Comment: Can you try allowing this setting from your firewall of your database https://i.imgur.com/1j3EotT.png. Also Can you make sure you are not restricting any ip addresses

Comment: I cheked it,always the same problem,foir this command CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'UNIQUE_STRING_HERE', should i create a random key?

Comment: yes, some random key

Comment: It still the same problem,i don't know why i get empty table

Comment: normally,i want to copy my data CSV file from sftp to mysql,tehre is another way to do this?Thanks

Comment: sure you can do this using ADF. Can you please check these SO Threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945067/ingest-data-from-on-premise-sftp-folder-to-azure-sql-database-azure-data-factor and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011176/how-to-bulk-copy-multiple-csv-files-from-blob-to-mutliple-sql-database-tables-wi

Comment: Thank you,there is a tutorial for this workflow using azure logic apps?

Comment: The one which I have added in the answer (i.e.. https://marczak.io/posts/azure-loading-csv-to-sql/) and https://www.sqlshack.com/azure-automation-use-azure-logic-apps-to-import-data-into-azure-sql-database-from-azure-blob-storage/

Comment: done,it work for me the tutorial,now i want to insert the data into Mysql,but i can't create stored procedure in Mysql,how can i insert the records?thank you